# Picking objects with ranges using input number in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have objects that have a min/max age range on them:

```
name: "Event 1"
type: Package # inheritance
min_age: 1
max_age: 8
category_id: 2 # Birthday
```

I would like to select and return these objects based on user preference of age and type by looking if the object's age range satisfies the inputted number.

Currently I am stuck with:

Controller code:

```
age = params[:age]
item_type = params[:item_type]
@all_items = Item.where("categories.name = ?", 'birthday')
@events = @all_items.where("(type: #{item_type}) AND ...here I need to lookup if the #{age} variable is within the object range")
```

Now the problem is that I need to pick a birthday event by inputted user number, having Range on the object itself. Is there a way of doing that without going through every single object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@events = @all_items.where("type = #{item_type} AND min_age >= #{age} AND max_age <= #{age}")
```

I suppose the associations look as follows:

```
Item has_many :categories
Category belongs_to :item
```

In this case

```
Item.where("categories.name = ?", 'birthday')
```

will most likely fail because `categories` are not joined with something like

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories"
```

Here is what you'll want to do:

```
Item.joins(:categories)
    .where(categories: { name: 'birthday' })
    .where("items.type = '#{item_type}' AND items.min_age >= #{age} AND items.max_age <= #{age}")
    .group('items.id')
```

Using [PostgreSQL's BETWEEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html) might make the query look nicer and shorter:

```
Item.joins(:categories)
    .where(categories: { name: 'birthday' })
    .where("items.type = '#{item_type}' AND #{age} BETWEEN items.min_age AND items.max_age")
    .group('items.id')
```

Comment: Consider about `BETWEEN` `where('? BETWEEN min_age AND max_age', age)`

Comment: awesome, thank you. one addition is that #{item_type} needs to be '#{item_type}' - with the quotes around it.

Comment: @TheWhizofOz correct ,edited. Glad it worked for you